# ArgumentError: hasproperty of NULL PyObject using PyPlot in julia 1.5.3 in JupyterNotebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, julia

I am a total newby at Julia but I've managed to do things with it using `Atom`. However, I kind of like writing in Jupyternotebook and thought I'd play around with things that have been working in `Atom` in notebooks.

But it does work. Take these line of code, for instance:

```
using PyPlot;
x = collect(Float16, range(0,pi,length=100));
y = collect(Float16, range(0,pi,length=100));
z = x.^2 + y.^2
surf(x,y,z);
PyPlot.display_figs()
```

They should return this (as they do in `Atom`)

[image]

But I get:

```
ArgumentError: hasproperty of NULL PyObject

Stacktrace:
 [1] pyhasproperty(::PyCall.PyObject, ::String) at C:\Users\k_sego\.julia\packages\PyCall\BcTLp\src\PyCall.jl:359
 [2] hasproperty at C:\Users\k_sego\.julia\packages\PyCall\BcTLp\src\PyCall.jl:365 [inlined]
 [3] gca(; kws::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Symbol,String,Tuple{Symbol},NamedTuple{(:projection,),Tuple{String}}}) at C:\Users\k_sego\.julia\packages\PyPlot\XHEG0\src\PyPlot.jl:174
 [4] plot_trisurf(::Array{Float16,1}, ::Vararg{Array{Float16,1},N} where N; kws::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at C:\Users\k_sego\.julia\packages\PyPlot\XHEG0\src\plot3d.jl:61
 [5] plot_trisurf at C:\Users\k_sego\.julia\packages\PyPlot\XHEG0\src\plot3d.jl:60 [inlined]
 [6] #surf#188 at C:\Users\k_sego\.julia\packages\PyPlot\XHEG0\src\plot3d.jl:94 [inlined]
 [7] surf(::Array{Float16,1}, ::Array{Float16,1}, ::Array{Float16,1}) at C:\Users\k_sego\.julia\packages\PyPlot\XHEG0\src\plot3d.jl:94
 [8] top-level scope at In[81]:6
 [9] include_string(::Function, ::Module, ::String, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1091
```

I've tried a variety of things....but with no luck. Glad for any help.